# Создать компонент, расширяющий пропсы BoxProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui

Так я пытаюсь использовать свой компонент `User`:

```typescript
<User
    component="a"
    href="test"
    user="User"
/>
```

Вот прототип реализации этого компонента:

```
import { Box, BoxProps } from "@mui/material";

export interface IUserProps extends BoxProps
{
    user: string;
}

export default function User({ user, sx = [], ...props }: IUserProps)
{
    return (
        <Box sx={[{}, ...Array.isArray(sx) ? sx : [ sx ]]} {...props}>
            {user}
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Я получаю следующую ошибку:

> Тип "{ component: "a"; user: string; href: string; }" не может быть назначен для типа "IntrinsicAttributes & IUserProps".
> Свойство "href" не существует в типе "IntrinsicAttributes & IUserProps". Вы имели в виду "ref"? ts(2322)

[image: Edit extends BoxProps]

Comment: А там точно верный импорт, не import { BoxProps } from '@material-ui/core/Box';
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Box, BoxProps } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <User
        component="a"
        href="test"
        user="User"
    />
  );
}

interface IUserProps
{
    user: string;
}

const  User = <C extends React.ElementType>(props: BoxProps<C, {component?: C}> 
& IUserProps )=>{
    return (
        <Box {...props}>
            {props.user}
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Вроде работает, стили нужно прокинуть

Comment: (property) component?: C | undefined
Parsing error: Type expected. (null)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/2k8i31V4FYve
CodeSandbox ни чего не фейлит

Comment: Кажется Code Sandbox словил какой-то баг, когда я проверял. Больше спасибо!)